# NoClassDefFoundError for java.awt.Rectangle in tomcat 8

Tags: java, tomcat, archlinux, tomcat8

I'm deploying a small Java servlet to tomcat 8. It draws an image and saves it to the hard drive. It makes use of the java.awt.Rectangle, java.awt.Image, and java.awt.Graphics2D classes. The relevant code is below.

```java
int WIDTH = 200;
int HEIGHT = 250;

Rectangle drawArea = new Rectangle(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

Image image = new BufferedImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) image.getGraphics();

//...
//use the dimensions of the drawArea to draw something on the gw
//...
```

It works perfectly during the development in Eclipse.

However, when I package it using maven and deploy it to an external server with a standard tomcat 8 running as a service, it complains about not being able to find the java.awt.Rectangle class.

The server runs OpenJDK (1.7.0_71) and tomcat 8 (running with `-Djava.awt.headless=true`). The result of listing the tomcat process (`ps -fp`) is as follows:

```
jsvc.exec -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8 -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp/tomcat8/temp -Djava.awt.headless=true -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar -user tomcat8 -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime -pidfile /var/run/tomcat8.pid -errfile SYSLOG -outfile SYSLOG org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
```

The rt.jar, which contains the java.awt.Rectangle, is found on the file system under the standard OpenJDK lib directory (`/usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime/lib/rt.jar`). HIt is not explicitly referenced by -cp in the tomcat arguments and IMHO it should be already on the classpath. It changes nothing, if I add it explicitely:

```
jsvc.exec -Dcatalina.home=/usr/share/tomcat8 -Dcatalina.base=/usr/share/tomcat8 -Djava.io.tmpdir=/var/tmp/tomcat8/temp -Dderby.system.home=/var/lib/derby -Djava.awt.headless=true -cp /usr/share/java/commons-daemon.jar:/usr/share/java/eclipse-ecj.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/share/tomcat8/bin/tomcat-juli.jar:/usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime/lib/rt.jar -user tomcat8 -java-home /usr/lib/jvm/default-runtime -pidfile /var/run/tomcat8.pid -errfile SYSLOG -outfile SYSLOG org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap
```

The server is a VM running the latest Arch linux on the local development machine for me to easily test the deployment of the servlet.

So the question is: *how* do I get java.awt functionality for generating an image in tomcat?

As I spent multiple hours on this and don't seem to be moving forward, I decided to bounce this off the heads of the more experienced. Any help greatly appreciated.

---

Edit (2015.01.22, added information based on the answer by @Moonwalker)

Basially, what I did to test is, editing `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tomcat8.service` followed by calling

```
systemctl daemon-reload
# and
systemctl restart tomcat8
```

I did 4 combinations of editing, by varying the following:

```
DISPLAY=localhost:0.0
or
DISPLAY=:0.0
```

and

```
-Djava.awt.headless=true
or
-Djava.awt.headless=false
```

All combinations result in:

```
threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Rectangle
```

The rt.jar does have the java.awt.Rectangle class.

---

Edit (2015.01.23, added the full stacktrace as suggested by @prunge)

```bash
Jan 22, 2015 9:49:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
                                                               SEVERE: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
                                                               com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.UnexpectedException: Service method 'public abstract void com.mytest.imagegeom.GeometryService.doGeom(java.lang.String) throws java.lang.IllegalArgumentException' threw an unexpected exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Rectangle
                                                                       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:415)
                                                                       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
                                                                       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:333)
                                                                       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:303)
                                                                       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:373)
                                                                       at com.gooJan 22 09:49:07 test-host-deploygle.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(Abst
Jan 22 09:49:07 test-host-deploy jsvc.exec[8963]: ractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
                                                                       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
                                                                       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                                                                       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportV
Jan 22 09:49:07 test-host-deploy jsvc.exec[8963]: alve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
                                                                       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
                                                                       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
                                                                       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
                                                                       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
                                                                       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
                                                                       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
                                                                       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
                                                                       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.jav
Jan 22 09:49:07 test-host-deploy jsvc.exec[8963]: a:61)
                                                                       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
                                                               Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class java.awt.Rectangle
                                                                       at com.mytest.com.mytest.imagegeom.GeometryServiceImpl.createPNG(GeometryServiceImpl.java:488)
                                                                       at com.mytest.com.mytest.imagegeom.GeometryServiceImpl.convertStringToTree(GeometryServiceImpl.java:479)
                                                                       at com.mytest.com.mytest.imagegeom.GeometryServiceImpl.doGeom(GeometryServiceImpl.java:265)
                                                                       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                                                                       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
                                                                       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                                                                       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
                                                                       at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:587)
                                                                       ... 28 more
```

Comment: What's the full stack trace.  Likely the `Rectangle` class was found but an exception was thrown from its static initializer while initializing AWT - which should be visible as an earlier exception in the logs.

Comment: I thought about that too, however this is the actual exception. I built a small GWT interface to call the servlet and attached the full stack trace in an edit of the original question for your convenience.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly enough, the problem got resolved after replacing OpenJDK7 with OpenJDK8 and removing all changes from `/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tomcat8.service`. It appears as if there was some kind of an incompatibility between the tomcat 8 and OpenJDK7. The exception is now magically gone. I'm able to reproduce it by returning to OpenJDK7, however I am not able to find out, what exactly causes this. I'm marking the question as solved, but still wellcome any input on this peculiar behavior.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first thing you should try is to set the headless option to false.

```
-Djava.awt.headless=false
```

The second thing you should do is to point the DISPLAY environment variable to a valid location. Without it, the awt will not work, even background image generation.

```
DISPLAY=localhost:0.0 or DISPLAY=:0.0
```

you may have to execute xhost + command but not necessarily. Hopefully your Linux install has virtual display installed and configured properly.

The third thing to check if the JRE you are using (and consequently CLASSPATH) have awt classes in it.

And yes...it should not be necessary to explicitly add JRE system jar files into the classpath...they should be picked up by default. But you should look into those jar files and verify awt packages are included.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you @Moonwalker, it seems you are onto something. I will test your solution and report the outcome in a couple of hours.

Comment: Still not working. Please see the edit of the original question. What I don't get is, why is tomcat not able to find the class, if it is in the classpath. It is a NoClassDefFoundError. If the problem were in the DISPLAY variable, shouldn't the error be something else? It seems, that I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: By the way, there is a package in Arch linux called jre7-openjdk-headless. It is installed.